# How do you upload video to imgur album with an account?

Tags: python, post, get, request, imgur

First I tried with to this url, https://api.imgur.com/3/image,  with an authorization header containing just the bearer token. In return I get a response of this, but the image shows up nowhere in my account and ticket is not mentioned in the imgur api. I next tried by adding the client id to the authorization header, but nothing changed.

```
{'data': {'errorCode': None, 'ticket': 'bfc74991'}, 'success': True, 'status': 200}
```

Next I tried with to this url, https://api.imgur.com/3/upload, with an authorization header of just the bearer token and I get an error of

```
{'errors': [{'id': '', 'code': '429', 'status': 'Too Many Requests', 'detail': 'Too Many Requests'}]}
```

However, I have plenty of credits to be used by both the account and client.

```
{'data': {'UserLimit': 2000, 'UserRemaining': 1996, 'UserReset': 1594517384, 'ClientLimit': 12500, 'ClientRemaining': 12449}, 'success': True, 'status': 200}
```

When I tried uploading without an authorization header, it works perfectly fine, but the image does not show up in my account.

During this whole time period, I can upload images perfectly fine to an album using an authorization header with just the bearer token. Images upload work perfectly fine, and anonymous video upload works perfectly fine, but for some reason I cannot upload a video linked to an account and I either get a ticket code, which has no data on it, or an error saying too many requests. I am certain I have requests available as I have plenty of credits on both the user and client, and I can upload images perfectly fine.

This is the code to upload videos

```
with open(path, "rb") as file: #Path is video path
    files = [('video', file)]
    data = {"type": "video/webm", "album": album_id}
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(acces_token)
    }
    response = requests.request('POST', imgur_upload_url, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)
    print(response.json())
```